# How to select a GtkTreeview row by id in C

Tags: c, gtk, gtktreeview

I want to select a GtkTreeview row by specifying an ID with the C GTK+ version.

I found this function:

```
gtk_tree_selection_select_iter (GtkTreeSelection *selection, GtkTreeIter *iter);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get GtkTreeSelection and GtkTreeIter items from a specific ID.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gtk_tree_view_get_selection()` to get GtkTreeSelection.

Use `gtk_tree_model_get_iter()` to get GtkTreeIter, which needs a GtkTreePath. And a GtkTreePath can be created by calling `gtk_tree_path_new_from_string()` or `gtk_tree_path_new_from_indices()`. Alternatively, if you already have a GtkTreePath, but want to move to next/previous iterator, you can call `gtk_tree_path_next()` or `gtk_tree_path_prev()`.

I've written a demo app for you. TreeSelection is changed when you press the spin button. Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/LiuLang/gtk-test/tree/master/GtkTreeIter).

Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Well I'm programming on C, not Python. DO you have an example in C ?

Comment: Hi, C version of GtkTreeView has been added, you can check it out now.